# identity matrix using dask in memory-efficient way

Tags: matrix, dask, identity

Do You guys know any idea how to create an Identity Matrix using Dask? Without using numpy.identity()?
I really care about memory consumption

Comment: What do you want to do with it? To just create a gigantic identity matrix with a small memory footprint I’d check out [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html). But we could give much more specific advice if you could show us an [mre] with the right data sizes to demonstrate how numpy would break

Comment: hmm actually - it looks like dask plays most nicely with the [pydata sparse](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html) project, which implements a sparse array object building on numpy and scipy but giving an NDArray interface rather than scipy.sparse's 2D matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Dask supports sparse arrays backed by the [`sparse`](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html) library, a pydata project implementing an ND sparse array. From the project description:

> This implements sparse arrays of arbitrary dimension on top of numpy and scipy.sparse. It generalizes the scipy.sparse.coo_matrix and scipy.sparse.dok_matrix layouts, but extends beyond just rows and columns to an arbitrary number of dimensions.
>
> Additionally, this project maintains compatibility with the numpy.ndarray interface rather than the numpy.matrix interface used in scipy.sparse
>
> These differences make this project useful in certain situations where scipy.sparse matrices are not well suited, but it should not be considered a full replacement. The data structures in pydata/sparse complement and can be used in conjunction with the fast linear algebra routines inside scipy.sparse. A format conversion or copy may be required.

You can create a `sparse.COO` identity array easily with [`sparse.eye`](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/sparse.eye.html). For example, here's we can create a 1e6 x 1e6 identity matrix, which would occupy ~1TB as a dense array but here occupies just over 17MB:

```py
In [11]: ident = sparse.eye(N=int(1e6), dtype='int8')

In [12]: ident.nbytes
Out[12]: 17000000
```

This can be indexed like a normal array:

```py
In [13]: ident[-8:-1, -8:-1]
Out[13]: <COO: shape=(7, 7), dtype=int8, nnz=7, fill_value=0>

In [14]: ident[-8:-1, -8:-1].todense()
Out[14]:
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int8)

In [15]: ident.shape
Out[15]: (1000000, 1000000)
```

Dask can work with this array type seamlessly - see the [dask docs on working with sparse arrays](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array-sparse.html). To convert the above array to a dask array, simply:

```py
In [16]: da = dask.array.from_array(ident)

In [17]: da
Out[17]: dask.array<array, shape=(1000000, 1000000), dtype=int8, chunksize=(10000, 10000), chunktype=sparse.COO>
```

Note, however, that some operations would cause this array to become dense, and potentially explode. The `sparse` library attempts to keep you safe by raising a ValueError for any operations that would cause "auto-densification", but it's probably worth giving the `sparse` docs on [Operations on `COO` and `GCXS` arrays](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/operations.html) a close read.

Additionally - note that Dask arrays don't take up less space - in fact, they take slightly more space, compared to their in-memory counterparts. Dask allows you to leverage multiple threads/processes or servers to either work with partitioned data stored on disk or using a distributed processing model, but it cannot magically save you memory.

Tl;dr you still have to be careful when performing large and especially sparse operations with dask. It just might be slightly faster (for you - not in terms of CPU time).